# Using ADB to mute on and off microphone during call

Tags: adb

I can call using below command to make a call:

"**adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL 0000000000**"

and during the call, tried to mute and unmute microphone using the command:

**"adb shell am start -a android.media.action.MICROPHONE_MUTE_CHANGED"**

But, I got an error message that

"Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.media.action.MICROPHONE_MUTE_CHANGED flg=0x10000000 }"

Can I know how to fix it?